# How to solve equations like $x/5 + \cos2x = 2$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm going through an old test paper. Some more info was given: the answer lies in the interval $-20\le x\le 20$. There are several solutions, the question is to find the smallest and the total number of solutions. The first solution is $5.996$, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get started on this problem.

Comment: Use  a rough plot by hand of $y=\cos 2x$ and $y=2-x/5$ to locate the appropriate solution approximately, then a numerical method.

Answer (score 1):

How to get started.... I would undoubtedly sketch a graph first.

[image]

As you know, mathematicians work it out with a pencil.